# Export Dart classes and functions to javascript

Tags: dart, dart-html, dart-js-interop

If I want to use Dart to create a js library, how can I export Dart classes and functions for use in javascript?

Is there something similar to scala.js, like this?

```
@JSExport
class Hello{
    num x = 0
    Hello(this.x)
}
```

So that in **javascript**, users can instantiate it as `var hi = new Hello(1)`

Answer (score 0):

In case this is still relevant: You can use the [dart2js compiler](https://webdev.dartlang.org/tools/dart2js), which will compile your dart code down to ES.